# Controlling the space between lines of an Array environment

Tags: lyx, arrays, phantom

I have an array enviroment in which the various lines are matrices. A simple example is

```
\begin_inset Formula 
\begin{align*}
A & =\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right]\\
 & =\left[\begin{array}{cc}
e & f\\
g & h
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

\end_inset
```

Unfortunately, LyX spaces the matrices on the first and second lines too close to each other. I therefore inserted a blank row in the array (making it 3x2 instead of 2x2, see code below), but now they are too far apart.

```
\begin_inset Formula 
\begin{align*}
A & =\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right]\\
\\
 & =\left[\begin{array}{cc}
e & f\\
g & h
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

\end_inset
```

I thought I might be able to control the height of the second row with a negative \hphantom, but none of my experiments have succeeded. I would be very appreciative for your suggestions on what I I might to achieve this.

Sincerely and with many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: don't use a blank row use `\\[some length]`  traditionally `\\[\jot]` but you can use any length you want eg `[5pt]`

Comment: also `\begin{bmatrix}`  gives nicer spacing than `\left[\begin{array}{cc}`

Comment: Thank you both. I experimented with both approaches and decided that I would go with \\[0.5em], as I had some difficulty using bmatrix.

Comment: the bmatrix comment was unrelated to your row space question, just a general comment that amsmath package provides bmatrix for [-] matrices and adjusts the spacing around the brackets compared to using array.

Comment: OK. I will look up bmatrix and try it again. Thanks for the pointer